# Custom image in AIR installer

Tags: flash, apache-flex, installation, air

Quite simply, is there a way to put a custom image in the installer of an AIR application, for example to the left.

I'm using `.air`-installers, which I need to preserve because of updating functionality. I create them with Flash Builder 4.5 + Flex 4.5.1 (AIR 2.6)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are referring to the image in the installer:

[image]

That image matches the application icon which is set via the application descriptor xml.  [This post](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Custom_AIR_application_icons-17505.html) describes how to set it.